# FP commands inside math mode

Tags: math-mode, fp

I face a strange problem running `fp` macros inside `tabenum` (`tablists` package) environment.
I use `fp` to generate some values that are presented with a personal
list environment based on `tabenum`.

The fact is that if I set a `fp` value outside the `tabenum`, I can reach it
inside the environment, but if I set it inside the environment, the
resulting value is unset. There are also strange behaviours according to
the place of the setting relatively to the `tabenumitem` commands.

For example, the following code

```
\begin{tabenum}
\FPmul\result{12}{10}
\tabenumitem \result
\end{tabenum}
```

will cause a `"unknown \result command" error`
while the following :

```
\FPmul\result{12}{10}
\begin{tabenum}
\tabenumitem \result
\end{tabenum}
```

will not.

My problem is that I what to generate several values using a `multido` command
inside the `tabenum` environement, so I cannot generate them before opening the
environment.

By trying a lot of examples, I discovered that the behaviour of the `fp` commands is changed inside the math mode. Maybe a solution could consist in getting
out the math mode for running the `fp` commands and getting back in it for displaying the values using `tabenumitem`.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. I, for one, have no idea what "fp macros" are so I can't help you.

Comment: As @Andrew says, a full example seems to be needed here. I I take your send snippet and add an appropriate preamble, _etc._ loading the `fp` and `tablists` packages then all seems to be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Tabular cells act as groups, therefore non-global definitions are gone after the group is closed.

- Either put the calculation inside the same cell or
- define a global macro.

Example for both:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tablists}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabenum}
    \tabenumitem
    \FPmul\result{12}{10}%
    \FPclip\result\result
    \result
  \end{tabenum}
  \begin{tabenum}
    \FPmul\result{21}{10}%
    \FPclip\result\result
    \global\let\gresult\result
    \tabenumitem\gresult
  \end{tabenum}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]